# Tag(s) for amorphous solids, glasses and quasicrystals

Tags: discussion, tags

I would like to discuss the creation of one or more tags for **[amorphous solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_solid), [glasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass) and [quasicrystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasicrystal)**.

There are many question on the site which address specifically glasses and the glass transition, for example [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23686/nature-of-glass-transition) and [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76185/glass-properties) and [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65740/is-glass-a-liquid).

Others are about amorphous solids in general, like [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/289916/non-glassy-amorphous-solids), [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/220302/why-polymeric-solids-are-said-to-be-intermediate-between-crystalline-solids-and) and [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/233430/why-is-amorphous-classified-solid/).

Finally, other questions are about quasicrystals, like [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82841/why-do-quasicrystals-have-well-defined-fourier-transforms) and [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26918/literature-on-fractal-properties-of-quasicrystals).

We have a tag for [spin glasses](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spin-glass), but not a tag for *glasses*. I find this to be pretty absurd.

I recently proposed the tag [**amorphous-solids**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amorphous-solids), but I'm wondering wether it could be useful to create the tag **glasses** (or glass) since someone asking a question about glasses will probably try to type "glass" instead of "amorphous".

Also, it could be useful to create a **quasicrystals** tag.

---

***Update***

Since the response has been mainly positive (or no one seriously objected, anyway...) I will create the **glass** tag. As for the **quasicrystals** tag, I still haven't decided what to do.

Comment: Quasicrystals are neither amorphous nor glasses. While all glasses are amorphous solids, not all amorphous solids are glasses (although that may well be a sub-field dependent distinction).

Comment: @JonCuster You are right about quasicrystals; I reformulated the question in order to make it conceptually correct. You are also correct about the rest, but I knew that already :-) Thanks.

Comment: I like the amorphous solids because it would allow the occasional polymer question to be tagged as well. I see your point about the glasses stuff too, though. Is there a disadvantage in creating both tags?

Comment: @Sanya I would prefer not to create too many new tags if not necessary. But I think that the "glass"/"glasses" tag is needed.

Comment: Hi valerio92, would you by any chance be willing to act as, say, a custodian/protector for these tags, i.e. when new (& old) questions appear, which need to be tagged appropriately?

Comment: @Qmechanic I would be glad to do it! Actually, I already started to do so with the "amorphous-solids" tag

Comment: I would say `go` on the quasicrystals as well, particularly if you can unify the existing questions under it.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Then I think I'll proceed with "quasicrystals" too.